# OAuth 2.0 Works for Google Sheets but not for Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am using the Google API for reading/writing Google Sheets and the Google Drive API.
I recently got assigned a project where it is necessary to send out Calendar invites. The Website is a JSF Page hosted on an Apache Tomcat 8.5. For other APIs, I am using a Service Account.
I now tried to authorize the Calendar Service same way but it fails. First line is the succesful authorize for the sheets service, its failing on the calendar service:

> GoogleConnection: Absolut Path: H:/ownCloud/Wabco/Workspace/WabcoDiagram/WebContent/resources/webserviceaccount.json
>   GoogleConnection: Absolut Path: H:/ownCloud/Wabco/Workspace/WabcoDiagram/WebContent/resources/webserviceaccount.json
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient$Builder;
>       at com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar$Builder.setBatchPath(Calendar.java:6758)
>       at com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar$Builder.(Calendar.java:6737)
>       at de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer.audit.AuditGoogleCalendar.getCalendarServiceLocal(AuditGoogleCalendar.java:112)
>       at de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer.audit.AuditGoogleCalendar.initializeCalendarServiceLocal(AuditGoogleCalendar.java:150)
>       at de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer.audit.AuditGoogleCalendar.main(AuditGoogleCalendar.java:156)

My Questions: 
Can I login with a Service account into the Google Calendar API, or what are the changes I have to do, or is there another error in my code somewhere?

Can I send out Calendar Invites from a Web Service Service account and make another user the Admin / Creator of the event, so he can change the event if necessary? Does this require "domain-wide authority"?
I am working for a company that uses GSuit.

Example Code. The local functions are for local testing.

```
package de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer.audit;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.plus.Plus;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;

public class AuditGoogleCalendar {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Wabco Audit";

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    // private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private static GoogleCredential credential;

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

    private static Plus plus;

    private static Sheets service;
    private static Drive driveService;
    private static Calendar calendarService;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials at
     * ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS, DriveScopes.DRIVE,
            GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM, CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);

    static {
        try {
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


    public static GoogleCredential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String relativeWebPath = "/resources/" + "webserviceaccount.json";
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getContext();
        String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
        System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Absolut Path: " + absoluteDiskPath);

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(absoluteDiskPath))
                .createScoped(SCOPES);
        return credential;
    }

    public static GoogleCredential authorizeLocal() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String absoluteDiskPath = "H:/ownCloud/Wabco/Workspace/WabcoDiagram/WebContent/resources/webserviceaccount.json";
        System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Absolut Path: " + absoluteDiskPath);

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(absoluteDiskPath))
                .createScoped(SCOPES);
        return credential;

    }

    public static Calendar getCalendarService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static Calendar getCalendarServiceLocal() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        Credential credential = authorizeLocal();
        return new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }

    public static Sheets getSheetsServiceLocal() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        credential = authorizeLocal();
        return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }

    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        GoogleCredential credential = authorize();
        return new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }

    public static void initializeSheetService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        service = getSheetsService();
    }

    public static void initializeSheetServiceLocal() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        service = getSheetsServiceLocal();
    }

    public static void initializeDriveService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        driveService = getDriveService();
    }

    public static void initializeCalendarService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        calendarService = getCalendarService();
    }

    public static void initializeCalendarServiceLocal() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        calendarService = getCalendarServiceLocal();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            initializeSheetServiceLocal();
            initializeCalendarServiceLocal();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Questions: Can I login with a Service account into the Google Calendar API, or what are the changes I have to do, or is there another error in my code somewhere?

Yes you can use a service account with Google Calendar.  Your code looks ok to me you should simply have to add the calendar scope which you have done and enable the google calendar api for the service account in Google developer console.

> Can I send out Calendar Invites from a Web Service Service account and make another user the Admin / Creator of the event, so he can change the event if necessary? Does this require "domain-wide authority"? I am working for a company that uses GSuit.

Yes you can with a service account. You are going to have to have the Gsuit admin grant the service account access to the calendar then it will be able to create events and invite people. Yes it will require "domain-wide authority"? Once you have inserted the event you should be able to **patch** the event and set someone else as organizer. [check this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource)  its been a while since i have done this cant remember more then that sorry.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply.
My Code is working for the for the sheets API, if I do the same with the calendar builder I get the error I posted above.
The Scope is already added and I also activated the Calendar API for the Account.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Seems like a false import? But when  I open the error location on eclipse source code, the method is present, so I am not exactly sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: I double checked the imports but everything seems correct.
It's trying to return:
com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient$Builder from the Method, which can't be found as method?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ok, the error was created from a version mismatch of one of the dependencies. I got the latest dependencies and cleaned the project and the error is gone.
I should switch to maven or gradle. ;-)

Thanks for the help on my other questions!